# How to save ListView with Chat in SharedPreference

Tags: android

I'm doing a `Chat with bubble`, whose dialogs are `saved in a ListView`, this is running ok, now I would like to `save this Chat in memory` and when I reopen the app I can follow the conversation, `similar to WhatsApp`. Can someone tell me if this can be done with `SharePreference` and how?

Here the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView listView;
private View btnSend;
private EditText editText;
boolean myMessage = true;
private List<ChatBubble> ChatBubbles;
private ArrayAdapter<ChatBubble> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ChatBubbles = new ArrayList<>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_msg);
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btn_chat_send);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_type);
    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.left_chat_bubble, ChatBubbles);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some text...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //add message to list
                ChatBubble ChatBubble = new ChatBubble(editText.getText().toString(), myMessage);
                ChatBubbles.add(ChatBubble);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText.setText("");
                if (myMessage) {
                    myMessage = false;
                } else {
                    myMessage = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here the error:
[image]

Comment: First error you need to use the variable of your List<ChatBubble> name, second error remove ArrayList and leave ChatBubble.class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Gson` : `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'`

For example

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ChatBubble);
mSharedPref.putString("chatList", json);
mSharedPref.apply();
```

And then to retrieve this :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<ChatBubble> mList = ArrayList<ChatBubble>();
String json = mSharedPref.getString("chatList", "");    
mList = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList<ChatBubble>.class);
```

Another way is to implements `Serializable` on your classes and then instead of `getString` just add `putExtra` and `getExtra`

To create the `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
editor.putString()...
```

### Edit

Create an arrayList as follows

```
ArrayList<ChatBubble> mList = new ArrayList<ChatBubble>();
```

You have to store the list for example in your onDestroy() or onStop()

```
private void saveChat(){
SharedPreferences mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ChatBubble);
editor.putString("chatList", json);
editor.apply();
}
```

And then everytime you go to your MainActivity in your onCreate() method you do this

```
private void setUpChat(){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mSharedPref.getString("chatList", ""); 
    ChatBubble[] mArray = gson.fromJson(json,ChatBubble[].class)   
    mList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mArray));
    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.left_chat_bubble, mList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: `Skizo-ozᴉʞS`, please can you give me a example more complete

Comment: What do you need more?

Comment: Effectively, this is how a `SharedPreferences` is created, but how do I apply it to my code, so that every time the application is opened and a chat is initiated, the other chats of the past days are loaded from memory, I need it to be identical to the behavior of the `WhatsApp messages`

Comment: In `ArrayList<ChatBubble>()` within the parentheses that parameters must go?

Comment: I think so, try it

Comment: What parameters?

Comment: Edited the answer, add the new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192006/discussion-between-skizo-oziks-and-w1ll).